# Attach "Tag" to element for styling

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-style

I've 9 button, which are `Polygon` inside a `Canva`. Each button is a "direction".

I need to have a special `Fill` color when they are "selected"(when I click on one direction, it set a property in the ViewModel.

I can easily do this like this:

```
<Button Command="{Binding SelectNewOrientationCommand}" CommandParameter="{x:Static local:OrientationEditorDirection.Top}" >
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Polygon Points="4,0 8,0 8,6 12,6 12,24 0,24 0,6 4,6"  RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,1.75" >
                <Polygon.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="Polygon">
                        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Blue" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedDirection, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                                         Value="{x:Static local:OrientationEditorDirection.Top}" />
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Polygon.Resources>
                <Polygon.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <TranslateTransform X="40" Y="4"/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Polygon.RenderTransform>
            </Polygon>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

This works, but it means that I've to copy-paste this style 9 times and do the maintenance 9 time.

I cannot put this "as is" in a Canva Resource, because I've to be able to specify individually for each button, for which values it triggers the specific value.

Is there a way to indicate that my button is for the `Top` value when I declare the button, and then in the Style to look for this "Top" value in my DataTrigger?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can have multiple DataTriggers - one for each direction - in one Style:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedDirection, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
             Value="{x:Static local:OrientationEditorDirection.Top}" >
     <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red"/>
</DataTrigger >
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedDirection, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
             Value="{x:Static local:OrientationEditorDirection.Bottom}" >
     <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Green"/>
</DataTrigger >
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood, but each button must of the same color, only the selected one should be in this color. With your example, ALL buttons will be in the same color, depending on which button I clicked on.

Answer (score 0):

You could create one base `Style` where you bind the `Fill` property of the `Polygon` in the `ControlTemplate` to a property of the `Button`, and then create a specific style that is based on the base style for each `Button`:

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Polygon Points="4,0 8,0 8,6 12,6 12,24 0,24 0,6 4,6"  RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,1.75"
                                 Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Polygon.RenderTransform>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <TranslateTransform X="40" Y="4"/>
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </Polygon.RenderTransform>
                </Polygon>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

---

```
<Button>
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedDirection, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                             Value="{x:Static local:OrientationEditorDirection.Top}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>

<Button>
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedDirection, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                             Value="{x:Static local:OrientationEditorDirection.Bottom}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

You cannot reuse the actual `DataTrigger`.

Comment: In fact it's almost the opposite that I'm looking for.

The Points of my polygon, the translations, ... are different for each button, so I cannot put this in common.

I'm looking for a way to have the same dataTrigger(except the `Value` value).

Comment: This is not possible. You cannot "reuse" a DataTrigger like this. If the Polygon is different for each Button, what is there to reuse? Then you should define a separate style or template for each one.

Comment: The colors are the same ;), also the source of the style trigger is the same.

Comment: Then define the colours as resources and reference them in each template.